# CSS for Drop down list popup based on the position that click on the mobile device

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am new to React.js. We use the material-io CSS framework to build our app.

I have a task to display menu items of in a dropdown menu, which opens to the top or bottom based on the position of the menu when it is opened on a mobile device..

It is similar to the Facebook video section when the user clicks the (...)-icon it shows the options based on the screen position of the icon.

[image: Facebook Top appear]

[Facebook bottom appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnLKF.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnLKF.png)

Facebook menu bottom appear

[image: Facebook bottom Appear]

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of a library that provides a tooltip menu. For example https://justinrhodes1.github.io/react-power-tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use react-power-tooltip. For Use:

1. Install From Npm
   `$ npm install react-power-tooltip --save`
2. import To Project
   `import Tooltip from 'react-power-tooltip'`
3. Add a hover state & mouse event handler to the enclosing target component

   ```
   class Test extends Component {
     state = {
       show: false
     }

     showTooltip = bool => {
       this.setState({ show: bool })
     }

     render() {
       return (
         {/* Target element position needs to be RELATIVE */}
         <div 
           style={{ position: 'relative' }}
           onMouseOver={() => this.showTooltip(true)} 
           onMouseLeave={() => this.showTooltip(false)}>

             {/* ADD TOOLTIP HERE */}

           </div>
       );
     }
   }
   export default Test;
   ```
4. Add the tooltip inside the target element

   ```
   {/* Add options/text via span elements */}
   <Tooltip show={this.state.show}>
     <span>Some text</span>
   </Tooltip>
   ```

For More Information:
https://justinrhodes1.github.io/react-power-tooltip/